# Access denied when uploading a document, how to set permission profile and bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need a bit of guidance how to set my S3 bucket policy and/or IAM permission profile.
Our Rails app uploads files to a bucket and shows links to the documents after uploading.
Basically I want to enable Block all public access , because it is secure, but from within the Rails app documents should be able to uploaded and opened when clicked on a link.
So I created a IAM user with this permission profile:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I added a bucket policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<iam-user>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With `"Action": "s3:*"`, I assume I'm saying: this user can do anything on this bucket?
This works for opening documents, but when uploading a document I get an access denied.
So what do I need to change to make uploading documents working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to give permission for an application to access (upload/download) an Amazon S3 bucket, then the  permissions should be granted **in an IAM policy placed on the IAM User or IAM Role** that the app is using. There is *no need* to also create a Bucket Policy.

That will allow the app to upload and download content.

When the app wants to permit a user to access a private object, it should generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. The URL can be inserted into HTML as a link or even in tags (eg `<img src='...'`).  This way, the application has full control over which users can access which objects.

Pre-signed URLs can also be used for **uploading objects to the bucket**. This way, the app controls who can upload an object and where they can put it. See: [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could create [S3 pre-signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html) for your files. This will enable visitors of your page to download them without making the explicitly public. The pre-signed urls are temporary, so you would need a mechanism for re-generation of the expired urls.

Other popular choice would be to expose your files through [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/). This way, your bucket can not only remain **fully private**, but you also get benefits of global CDN that can server your files faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but at the moment the issues are with uploading a file. Listing and  downloading is not an issue, so I want to solve that first.

Comment: @John Your rails app will use probably your instance role, not IAM user. Have you setup any instance role? What permissions does it have?

Comment: Hi Marcin, no I don't have an instance role, where can I do that? The Rails app uses the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key of the IAM user.

Comment: @John This is bad practice. You should use IAM roles whenever possible, which includes [ec2 instance roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).